# WinPhone 8 RadTextBox - unable to set PhoneForegroundBrush color

Tags: windows-phone-8, textbox, telerik, foreground

I am developing an app for Win Phone 8 SDK using Telerik controls its RadTextBox. I need to change the foreground color for different theme's - dark / light.

In my xml :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives" 
x:Class="PanicMe.OptionPages.ProfilePage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:telerikCore="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Core"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PanicMe.Controls"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">


<Controls:RadTextBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
 Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" ClearButtonVisibility="Visible" 
 Watermark="First Name" />
```

In my xml.cs :

```
    public ProfilePage()
    {
        Resources.Remove("PhoneForegroundBrush");
        Resources.Add("PhoneForegroundBrush", System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red);
        // THIS BELOW LINE SHOWS ERROR
        //((System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"]).Color = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Magenta;

        InitializeComponent();

        Resources.Remove("PhoneForegroundBrush");
        Resources.Add("PhoneForegroundBrush", System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red);
    }
```

I tried different ways to set the value for PhoneForegroundBrush, but I don't see any difference in output results. The problem I am facing is with dark/light themes. How can I set 1 color so it can be workable (Text in the textbox be visible) in all cases.

I am a newbie for WinPhone8 development, please help me to your best.

Thanks

Comment: tel me clearly. what color you want to set as the ForeGround brush ?

Comment: @MohamedThaufeeq was wondering which color will go for light & dark both the themes. I guess will go with Blue shade.

Answer (score 0):

instead OF USING pHONEfOREGROUNDbRUSH, I use PhoneAccentBrush. This did the trick for text box.

TextBox's background when in focus will be the Phone's foreground color in this if the text is also written in same color then it wont be visible. Hence I changed the foreground color to PhoneAccentBrush value, which makes sure that in all cases text is visible.

And it did the trick.

Hope this helps someone.